# xbuild fails to embed resources from shared project

Tags: c#, mono, xbuild

I have a C# project *A* located in *FolderA* which references a shared project *B*. The files of the shared project are located in *FolderB*. The shared project *B* contains a file *C.gz* with the properties

> *Build Action* **Embedded Resource**
> *Copy to Output Directory* **Do Not Copy**

When I try to build project *A* using **xbuild** (specifically versions 4.8 and 4.8.1, x86 and x64 architectures):

```
xbuild A.csproj
```

I get the following build error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\xbuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.targets (CopyNonResxEmbeddedResources target) ->
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\lib\mono\xbuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.targets: error : Cannot copy FolderA\C.gz to FolderA\obj\Release\C.gz, as the source file doesn't exist.

i.e. **xbuild** searches for the embedded resource file in *FolderA* although it is apparently located in *FolderB* together with the other files of the shared project *B*.

It is not a feasible option for me to move the embedded resource file to project *A*, as the shared project is referenced from several other projects as well.

Is there something else I can do to make project *A* build successfully with **xbuild**?

---

Side note: is this an expected behavior in **xbuild**, or is it a bug? With **msbuild** I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue appears to be a flaw in the current *xbuild* implementation, so I needed to apply a workaround specific for this problem.

Since *xbuild* expects the embedded resource file to be available in the *FolderA* folder, I simply add a pre-build step in the project file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <FilesToCopy Include="..\FolderB\C.gz" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="."/>
</Target>
```

Optionally, one could also consider a cleanup after building by removing the copied file in the post-build.

**Note!** To ensure that the pre-build step is properly accounted for, make sure to place it *after* this line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```